# what is value of $(a_0+a_1)\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

If

> $$\displaystyle\sin \pi x= a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos(n\pi x)$$
>   for $0<x<1$,then $(a_0+a_1)\pi=?$

**Solution I tried**-
I write $\sin \pi x=\sqrt(1-\cos^{2} \pi x$ which can be written as

$\displaystyle\sqrt(1-\frac{1+\cos2 \pi x}{2})$

further i am not gettiing how to solve

please help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By the definition of Fourier cos series
$$ a_0=\int_0^1\sin (\pi x) dx \\
 a_1=\int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) \cos(\pi x) dx $$

Just calculate them